# How should we tag "Anime de Wakaru Shinryounaika"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently asked [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23819/49) regarding the anime [*Anime de Wakaru Shinryounaika*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/27911/Anime_de_Wakaru_Shinryounaika). I've used the tag [anime-wakaru-shinryonaika](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-wakaru-shinryonaika), since using the full title would go way over the 25 character limit. So I had to cut the "de", which wouldn't be too much of a problem, IMO. However, I also had to cut a "u" from the last word, turning "shinryounaika" into "shinryonaika".

This is probably fine, since we can't do much about the character limit, but I just thought I'd check if anyone know about any shorter version of the tile I'm unaware of — like "oreimo", "watamote", "waramete" and so on — or a better alternative for the tag.

Comment: What does it translate to? would just "Wakaru Shinryounaika" make sense?

Comment: It would translate to something like "Psychosomatic medicine can be understood through anime". So "Wakaru Shinryounaika" would mean something like "Understand[ing?] psychosomatic medicine". It could make sense, given that the manga substitutes anime for manga (of course).

Answer (score 6):

There is no real canon abbreviation, so you have to consider your own.

You have a variety of choices to consider:

1. Used the abbreviated channel names for the series on [series domain](http://mental-anime.jp/) [NND](http://ch.nicovideo.jp/mental-anime) and [YT](https://www.youtube.com/user/mentalanimeproject), [mental-anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-anime)
2. Take the first and last part, [anime-shinryounaika](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-shinryounaika), this makes it distinct enough to be about psychosomatics and anime
3. Make and use a English abbreviation, like [comical-psychosomatic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comical-psychosomatic)

The title is more or less, in a literal sense, "Understand with Anime, Psychosomatic Medicine."

Keeping "psychosomatic" and "anime" together is important. Adding at least an excerpt to the tag wiki (for context) relating it back to the title and synonyms (in case they type "anime de wakaru") will help in recognition by users, too.

Including the title in the body might also help.

Comment: [tag:anime-shinryounaika] seems reasonable. Do you think we should try to make this work for the manga too? 'Cause if so, then that wouldn't be an option.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to worry about question about the manga. Given that we're primarily English site, it makes more sense to use the English names. But due to it being a new series it doesn't have as much exposure as the original in romanized form. It might make more sense to use the English title if you want to be all inclusive.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can synonym the others (and I think [mental-...] is a good one since some people will type that word in).